# Custom Profile Page JetStream LiveWire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I have a quick question. Why when creating a new view with the following code:

```
@if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasAccountDeletionFeatures())
   @livewire('profile.delete-user-form')
@endif
```

and after adding **<livewire:scripts />** in the body and **<livewire:styles />** in the head the functionality is not working?

How can i create custom profile page and just add these components where necessary?

Comment: use `@livewireScripts` `@livewireStyles` .component  : `<livewire:profile.delete-user-form />`

Comment: @MohammadrezaGolshahi Still not working. When clicking on the Delete Account button the pop up is not showing.

Comment: Any Other Ideas? @MohammadrezaGolshahi